# Adding images to product gallery -- Can't get media type to stick

Tags: php, magento

I'm trying to add base, small, and thumbnail images to all of my products programmatically. The images are importing fine and being placed into `/media/catalog/product` as expected, but only 'Base Image' is selected when I view the product's images in the Magento backend.

I'm looping through each product in the catalog and running:

```
$mediaArray = array('thumbnail', 'small_image', 'image');   
$file = Mage::getBaseDir('media') . DS . 'import' .  trim($imageName);
try {
    $product->addImageToMediaGallery($file, $mediaArray, false, false);
    $product->save();
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
```

All of my image names start with a slash, and the images themselves are uploaded to `/media/import`. I'm attempting to mimic what the Mage product importer would do.

Any insight on why the small and thumbnail flags aren't being set would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: in `$product->addImageToMediaGallery($file, $mediaArray, false, false);` does the `addImageToMediaGallery()` expect an array or a string for the second parameter?

Comment: `@param string|array  $mediaAttribute    code of attribute with type 'media_image', leave blank if image should be only in gallery`

Comment: What do you mean by "base media type?" Only one of your three is being tagged?

Comment: Here's were I determined an array should work: `Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Attribute_Backend_Media::setMediaAttribute()` which is called from the same class's `addImage`, which is invoked from the product's `addImageToMediaGallery` function.

Comment: Yes, only one of three is being tagged, the base image. I edited my question to hopefully explain that better.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is my own import code I used, that worked:

```
        // Add three image sizes to media gallery
        $mediaArray = array(
            'thumbnail'   => $oscProduct['products_image'],
            'small_image' => $oscProduct['products_mediumimage'],
            'image'       => $oscProduct['products_largeimage'],
        );

        // Remove unset images, add image to gallery if exists
        $importDir = Mage::getBaseDir('media') . DS . 'import/';

        foreach ( $mediaArray as $imageType => $fileName ) {
            $filePath = $importDir . $fileName;
            if ( file_exists($filePath) ) {
                try {
                    $product->addImageToMediaGallery($filePath, $imageType, false);
                } catch (Exception $e) {
                    echo $e->getMessage();
                }
            } else {
                echo "Product does not have an image or the path is incorrect. Path was: {$filePath}<br/>";
            }
        }
```

Note `$imageType` is not an array, as your counterpart is.

**Edit:** You only want one image, and to set it as each type. After you save the product with `$product->save()`, try something like the following, assuming you have set the `image` type already:

```
$product->setThumbnail($product->getImage());
$product->setSmallImage($product->getImage());
$product->save();
```

Comment: That will add 3 unique images to the gallery, whereas I want one image used as the base, small, and thumbnail. Maybe I should Add the image to the gallery, and in another operation set that image as the small and thumbnail?

Comment: You can set the all values in $mediaArray as the same value.

Comment: Yep, I've tried that. It will add 3 images to the gallery, all the same. Am I mistaken? (I've attempted this so many times that its possible I had some leftover images on that specific try)

Comment: Cool, thanks for explaining. My updated code should help you ;)

Comment: Wow, so simple. Ima give that a try. Thanks!

Comment: `$product->setThumbnail()` is not setting the thumbnail flag.

Comment: The same thing happened with `small_image`. I'm starting to believe its my install or database.

Answer (score 0):

I was duplicating products and wanted to copy the product images over also.

I worked at this for hours and could not get array('thumbnail', 'small_image', 'image') to actually set those values. It would add the image to the library but not set the above types. I also tried inputting as a string, just 'image' for example instead of the array and this also did not work. In the end this is all that worked for me:

```
//grab the pics from original product
$mediaApi = Mage::getModel("catalog/product_attribute_media_api");
$items = $mediaApi->items($product->getId());

//duplicate the product
$product = $product->duplicate();
$product->setStatus(1);

//also move the pics over
$product->setMediaGallery (array('images'=>array (), 'values'=>array ()));
$product->setImage($items[0]['file']);
$product->setThumbnail($items[0]['file']);
$product->setSmallImage($items[0]['file']);
```

Answer (score 0):

It Will not stick unless you have set the `store id`.

I did this:

```
Mage::app()->getStore()->setId(Mage_Core_Model_App::ADMIN_STORE_ID);
```

I have only one store.